# Should I use perturbation theory with finite matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Is there any use for perturbation theory when the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian operator is a finite-dimensional? It is supposed to be applicable in continuous infinite-dimensional systems. You can solve finite Hamiltonian analytically, right?

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you think it shouldn't be possible?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Is there a reason for why you think that perturbation theory is only applicable to infinite-dimensional systems?

Comment: That's not what I said, in the contrary. The question is what's the point if any in using the method when the dimensionality is finite and the problem is solvable analytically.

Comment: why would you think that a finite dimensional problem is always solvable analytically?

Comment: Solving for the eigenvalues of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix involves finding the roots of a degree-$n$ polynomial. If $n>4$ there is no analytic route to finding the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot in general solve analytically every finite dimensional problem.  Even though it is technically possible to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a (comparatively simple) cubic equation analytically, the solutions are typically uninsightful and complicated.  There is no solution by radical to general polynomial equations of degree $5$ or higher, thus no chance of finding the analytical expressions for eigenvalues of a $5\times 5$ matrix, unless one can identify a symmetry to help with the diagonalization.  Of course it is possible to find approximate numerical eigenvalues for any finite-sized matrix (although it might require non-trivial effort depending on the accuracy required).

In addition, issues with eigenvectors arise if there are repeated eigenvalues as eigenvectors are not unique.

For instance, as we know that the eigenvalues of $L_x$ must be those of $L_z$ on physical grounds, it’s possible to diagonalise $L_x$ in the space of states with $\ell=2$, but that’s not exactly a *general* $5\times 5$ matrix.

As a result, perturbation theory is immensely useful for finite dimensional matrices.  Indeed, many “breakthrough” results occur when one finds a way of partially diagonalizing a finite dimensional matrix, especially if this results in off-diagonal entries such that perturbation theory can be used.

In some cases, even partial block diagonalization of is enough, especially if further numerical treatment is to be applied.  A common method of block diagonalization is rooted in Lie symmetries (if there are any) and the organization of basis states into irreducible representations of the corresponding Lie group or algebra.  An example of this would be the diagonalisation of $J^2$ and $J_z$ in a problem with two particles of angular momenta $L_1$ and $L_2$: in the uncoupled basis, this is a $(2L+1)(2L_2+1)\times (2L_1+1)(2L_2+1)$ matrix; the basis which diagonalises $J^2$ and $J_z$ is constructed using CG coefficients, which can be computed for any $L_1, L_2$ using $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ algebraic methods only.